# Publish with Visual Studio vs. MSBuild

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a project that builds properly, but fails in Teamcity. Since Teamcity relies on MSBuild, I ran msbuild manually to see the problem.

So, I take the .net 4.7 / asp.net / core .net 2.0 project and clone it into 2 folders:

On one, I do a build and publish with VS: no errors

On the other folder, I do:

```
msbuild Test.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" /t:publish
```

and I get 2 errors  (twice the same for different libs)

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.0.0\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\build\Microsoft.NET.Publish.targets(249, 5): error MSB4018: The "ResolvePublishAssemblies" task failed unexpectedly.
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: path1
   at System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.PublishAssembliesResolver.<GetResolvedFiles>d__7.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.PublishAssembliesResolver.Resolve(ProjectContext projectContext)
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.ResolvePublishAssemblies.ExecuteCore()
   at Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
```

I can't really find good info since everything about this error is about beta versions of .net 2.0

Any idea?

Comment: it would help to get a diagnostic or binary log from the build. could you add `/bl` to the command and upload the resulting `msbuild.binlog` file? You could even open an issue at https://github.com/dotnet/sdk about it since this is where the failing task comes from.

Comment: I just did the same post on on their github (https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/1542) I will post any answers here.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of .NET 2.0 (not beta)?

Comment: Can try this command? `msbuild Test.sln /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:PublishProfile=<profile-name>  /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU" `

Comment: yes, I'm using the final version of .NET 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved through information from:

[dotnet restore vs. nuget restore with teamcity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45897271/dotnet-restore-vs-nuget-restore-with-teamcity)

I had another project with different errors, but similar problems and the information posted there allowed to solve both.

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues.