# How to fix AppCenter build error NETSDK1004

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-app-center

I decided to give a try to AppCenter CI to build my Xamarin project on Android & iOS.

However I have a build error that I don't meet when building directly in VisualStudio. Have you got any idea how to solve this prob ? Cause it tells me to run a Nuget Package restore, but during the build NugetPackage were restored.

```
Installed:
    168 package(s) to packages.config projects
##[section]Finishing: Restore Nuget
##[section]Starting: Build Xamarin.Android project 

error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject/obj/project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/Users/vsts/agent/2.148.1/work/1/s/MyProject/MyProject/MyProject.csproj]

    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.99
##[error]Error: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5_16_0_0/bin/msbuild failed with return code: 1
```

Build output logs :

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1uWbhzDOEF6KoRlC8iGhD_ro9NEyeODu5

I checked the Target SDK version in the build setting in AppCenter, and I was targetting SDK 9.1 (Mono 5.16) ... But, I changed it to SDK 9.0 (Mono 5.12), so the one I'm targetting in my project, prob still here.

EDIT : I also noticed this error while appcenter restoring nuget package :

```
[command]/bin/bash -c /usr/bin/find . -name '*.sln' -type f -print0 | /usr/bin/xargs -0 grep -l '***.Droid.csproj' | /usr/bin/xargs -I '{}' nuget restore '{}' -DisableParallelProcessing
MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0' from '/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.12.0/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin'.
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018: The "WriteRestoreGraphTask" task failed unexpectedly. [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018: NuGet.Commands.RestoreCommandException: PackageTargetFallback and AssetTargetFallback cannot be used together. Remove PackageTargetFallback(deprecated) references from the project environment. [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at NuGet.Commands.AssetTargetFallbackUtility.EnsureValidFallback (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] packageTargetFallback, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] assetTargetFallback, System.String filePath) [0x0002d] in <55431ab4846b49babe0aafcf24cd67ed>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at NuGet.Commands.MSBuildRestoreUtility.AddPackageTargetFallbacks (NuGet.ProjectModel.PackageSpec spec, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) [0x000cb] in <55431ab4846b49babe0aafcf24cd67ed>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at NuGet.Commands.MSBuildRestoreUtility.GetPackageSpec (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) [0x002b3] in <55431ab4846b49babe0aafcf24cd67ed>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectEnumerableIterator`2[TSource,TResult].MoveNext () [0x00048] in <cc3b329d40bd4675ae0e985e302972af>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereEnumerableIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext () [0x0004e] in <cc3b329d40bd4675ae0e985e302972af>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at NuGet.Commands.MSBuildRestoreUtility.GetDependencySpec (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] items) [0x001f8] in <55431ab4846b49babe0aafcf24cd67ed>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at NuGet.Build.Tasks.WriteRestoreGraphTask.Execute () [0x000a5] in <55431ab4846b49babe0aafcf24cd67ed>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute () [0x00023] in <2338fdb301034c1d9c6b95e564d514b0>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]
/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/wnqwdckn.p7q.nugetrestore.targets(143,5): error MSB4018:   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder+<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext () [0x00212] in <2338fdb301034c1d9c6b95e564d514b0>:0  [/var/folders/24/8k48jl6d249_n_qfxwsl6xvm0000gn/T/NuGetScratch/u4qrmymw.ehn.nugetinputs.targets]

WARNING: Error reading msbuild project information, ensure that your input solution or project file is valid. NETCore and UAP projects will be skipped, only packages.config files will be restored.
```

Comment: Can you add the build log of the error that would help in here

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore

Comment: @G.hakim added output. 
yyou I tried to add a pre-build script with a dotnet restore command w/o success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Finally fixed my prob.**

1/ I had an external assembly in my project that was not on nuget. I read that appcenter can't build a project / restore nuget if there is an assembly that does not depend on Nuget. So I updated this assembly with a nuget provided by the author.

2/ Edit I made with logs drove me on the right path.

> The "WriteRestoreGraphTask" task failed unexpectedly

Solution to this is edit project .csproj and modify the line that allows fallback on .NET 4.5 from

`<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</PackageTargetFallback>`

**to**

`<AssetTargetFallback>$(AssetTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wp8+wpa81;</AssetTargetFallback>`

Ref : https://intercom.help/appcenter/build/xamarin/xamarin-build-fails-with-the-writerestoregraphtask-task-failed-unexpectedly

Now I got a sucessfull build.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error with NETSDK1004. It seems the project.assets.json never gets generated because of an earlier failure.

**Error Generated**

```
error NETSDK1004: Assets file '/Users/runner/work/1/s/.../project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

**Actual Error**

In my case there was an earlier error in 9_Restore_Nuget task for App Center: NETSDK1045.

```
error NETSDK1045: The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.1.  Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.1.
```

I had put a DLL in there targeting net core 3.1 - App Center didn't like it & then failed the package restore.

So, the original error is true - project.assets.json isn't there but there is a reason & that needs exploring earlier in the build process.

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar error: `error netsdk1004 assets file 'C:\Users\username\source\repos\...\project.assets.json not found Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.`

All I had to do to fix it was open command prompt and then navigate to my project directory and run `dotnet restore`. This resolved the issue and I was able to successfully restore all .csproj files and thus build. Hope this helps!

This link helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1004