# Visual Studio 2019 not restoring NET Standard 2.0 project dependencies correctly

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

I have a solution with a number of Net Standard 2.0 projects. I have opened the project and restored dependencies.  The Net Standard projects do not appear to have their references resolved (yellow exclamation). It appears that the packages have been downloaded correctly as I can see them in my local user nuget cache.

I am unsure of what may be causing this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem wasn't related to Net Standard 2.0. There was a space in the folder name of the git repository. I found the answer in this SO. [Assets file project.assets.json not found. Run a NuGet package restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore)

Comment: Hi Andrew, thanks for your sharing and please mark your reply as [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and that will help other community members who easier search this useful information, it just a reminder :)