# VS 2019 Error style attribute styles.xml not found

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

salam,
i have big problem here about visualstudio 2019 using xamarin.
i keep try to fix some problem but stil didnt work.
[check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSujO.png)
and this is my first style my styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<resources>

  <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!--drawable/splashscreen >> from image | drawable/splash From xml logo -->
    <!--<item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splashscreen</item>-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
  </style>
```

hope you guys can help me. Thanks advance

Comment: I test the style with your xml, it works well. You could check the screenshot. https://imgur.com/1uphp7u Try the following steps. Delete the obj and bin folder, clean the project and rebuild. It would fix the error.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thanks for helping, but i try that before its not working, i try to reinstall my visual studio and not working to.

Comment: I upload my test demo on GitHub, you could download for reference. https://github.com/WendyZang/Test/tree/master/SplashScreenThemeDemo

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT thank you so much for helping me again sir, I download sample and try, and got same error like my problem, you can check my screenshoot here https://imgur.com/CLlKs9U, or did i miss something sir? because me new in visual studio. Thanks again for help.

Comment: A error occured in your error list (assets file project.assets.json not found, Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file), follow the steps below to add the required files would fix this error. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore After that, clean and rebuild the project, if the error still exists, provide the details. You could try to repair the VS as well.

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT wow its working sir, haha the problem on nuget package, thank you so much for helping me, god bless you sir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A error occured in your error list (assets file project.assets.json not found, Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file), follow the steps below to add the required files would fix this error.

[Assets file project.assets.json not found. Run a NuGet package restore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore)

After that, clean and rebuild the project.