# I have to run "dotnet restore" through the Package Manager Console before being able to build my applications

Tags: c#, .net-core

I had a problem where I received the error: [Nuget error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKnXj.png) when trying to build my applications.
I found a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore)
The solution was to run `dotnet restore` through the Package Manager Console. It helped, but ever since I have to do it for every single project I make. Before this error I have never had this problem

It are .net Core projects in visual studio community 2019

Is there something I can change so I don't have to run `dotnet restore` before every build.

Edit: added what I was looking for

Comment: If you have multiple projects, you can right click the solution -> Restore Nuget Packages.

Comment: Can you help us to answer your questions by including a question? Do you want Visual Studio to automatically restore things? Do you want to find a point-and-click way of restoring things? What's your end goal?

Comment: @omajid Yes ofcourse I added my end goal. I'm looking for a solution so I don't have to run dotnet before every build.

Answer (score 1):

I once had the same problem when working on Xamarin Forms application, I noticed the problem occurred when there was a disruption in the build/compiling process, because I had experienced power shortage and the laptop went off in between the process.

The fix was to delete the file projects.assets.json, and after that it compiled successfully.