# Path changed in solutions file Visual Studio 2019, now can't build file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, namespaces

I cut my project and pasted it in a different folder, and now it doesn't work anymore due to it not finding the correct path (which I deliberately changed).

Now my path looks like: `\source\repos\App%name%with%spaces\namespacename\solutionfile.sln`,
which used to be: `\source\repos\namespacename\namespacename.sln`.

Basically, I put the whole project in another folder called `App%name%with%spaces`.

Now I get errors that they can't find the `projects.assets.json` file. Does anyone know a solution to this?

EDIT: The "%" in the foldername is supposed to be a space. The spaces had been automatically changed to `%`, so change the foldername to a name without spaces, because it is sensitive to that. E.g. change
`App name with spaces\namespacename\solutionfile.sln` to `App_name_with_underscores\namespacename\solutionfile.sln`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was apparently due to the folder name having spaces in the project. This answer has been found in this thread: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore`.

If this is your issue, just rename the GIT repository when you clone

`git clone http://Your%20Project%20With%20Spaces newprojectname`

Answer (score 0):

Moving an entire solution folder generally does not cause problems like you are experiencing, as files and folders in your solution and project (.sln/.__proj) files are specified by relative paths.

With that out of the way, this specific error is generally fixed by running:

Tools > NuGet Package Manager > Package Manager Console:

then execute this command:

```
dotnet restore
```