# How to Get Rid of dotnet tool restore error Under Entity Framework Migrations

Tags: asp.net, .net, razor-pages, publish

I am trying to publish a web app to IIS and I am getting this error in my publishing profile.
[image: dotnet tool restore screenshot]

Underneath that it gives me the path to my dotnet-tools.json file and says, "...dotnet-tools.json came from another cmputer and might be blocked to help protect this computer. For more information, including how to unblock, see https://aka.ms/motw.

I went to the site listed, but frankly everything there was way over my head. I have Googled and read multiple posts, but cannot seem to find a solution. One post said to right click on the file, the properties and on the General tab, check the "unblock" box near the bottom. I have no such box on my file!

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is quite old, but I ran into a similar issue and found a solution that worked for me.

Navigate to the particular file that is causing the issue (for me it was `../.config/dotnet-tools.json`). Right-click the file and view its properties.

There was a checkbox near the bottom of the properties window allowing me to 'Unblock' the file.

[image]

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score 0):

Clean the solution then rebuild the solution
or go to the project folder find  "bin" folder and delete it, then clean and rebuild the solution.

Comment: Do you mean "cleaN"? I have done that and a rebuild and still get the error.

Comment: yes, try to delete bin folder and then clean and rebuild
Have you tried to make a new publish profile?

Comment: I deleted bin folder. Cleaned solution. Rebuilt solution. Still get the same error.

Comment: then, probably some packages are missing in your application, such as Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools or Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design, I had the same problem last year and I forgot how I fixed it, try this and let me know if it didn't work!

Comment: Nope. Nothing works yet. I found this link about a name possibly being wrong? but don't know what they mean or how to check. Do you have any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48440223/assets-file-project-assets-json-not-found-run-a-nuget-package-restore/48440777#48440777

Comment: As I said probably the packages in
top meenu go to "Tools" -> "NuGet Package Manager" -> "Manage NuGet Console"
Manage NuGet Console windows will open usually at the bottom of your VS windows than run PM> dotnet restore
it will restore and update your packages

Comment: I have run dotnet restore. It returns this:   Determining projects to restore...
  All projects are up-to-date for restore. But I still have the error. Is there something that has to be done after that step? I am new to programming, so please explain in detail. Thanks.

Comment: I am on 7.0 packages and I did not have this problem before I updated VS to its latest version. I then also updated to 7.0. Maybe I should try rolling back to 6.9 packages?

Comment: Or maybe it was the last VS update that did it? I tried uninstalling it and reinstalling it. That did not help either.

Comment: I wish I could, but cannot due to my employer.