# What nuget version is used by dotnet CLI /when do nuget features make it into the dotnet CLI?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, nuget

I have both a specific and a broader question, and I'll use the specific one to illustrate the broader:

My use case is that I want to use this feature [Support pre release packages with floating versions](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Support-pre-release-packages-with-floating-versions), which will be available in Nuget 5.6, both for local development and in my CI/CD pipelines for my .NET Core applications

So basically I want to use this feature in combination with:

1. the standalone nuget.exe CLI (for local dev)
2. Visual Studio (for local dev)
3. [dotnet CLI's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/dotnet-commands)  `dotnet restore command` (for local dev and for my pipelines)

For (1), it's pretty simple, when 5.6 is released, I can use it.

For (2), I found on [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-5.3) that each Nuget 5.x version was available in Visual Studio 16.x, so I guess  theres's a good chance, that, when Visual Studio 16.6 is out, nuget 5.6 will be used there as well. (Couldn't find any other docs specifying this)

For (3), I have no idea.

So my specific question/problem was: When will I be able to use package reference versions like "*-*" that [will](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/wiki/Support-pre-release-packages-with-floating-versions#scenarios) use the latest release or prerelease version available and be able to run a `dotnet restore` command that understands this? As soon as nuget 5.6 comes out?

I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45899966) that

> The only difference: dotnet restore is a convenience wrapper to invoke
>   dotnet msbuild /t:Restore which invokes an MSBuild-integrated restore.
>   This only works on MSBuild distributions that include NuGet, such as
>   Visual Studio 2017 (full Visual Studio, build tools) or Mono 5.2+ (=>
>   msbuild /t:Restore) and the .NET Core SDK which provides this
>   convenience command.

but again, which nuget version is used?

But my broader question coming from this is: What nuget version does the dotnet CLI use? Can you even say it uses a specific "version" or does it just contain a certain subset of features of nuget that do not really correspond to a version?
Is there any documentation/process specifying when features of nuget make it into the dotnet CLI?

Comment: Reach out to https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues please.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> What nuget version does the dotnet CLI use? Can you even say it uses a
>   specific "version" or does it just contain a certain subset of
>   features of nuget that do not really correspond to a version?

Since `Net Core 2.1`, dotnet cli contains partial `nuget.exe cli` functionality subsets rather than full `nuget.exe cli`, such as package projects, push packages, delete packages, restore packages, and so on.

Each `dotnet cli` corresponds to a version of the `nuget.exe cli`.

**In fact**, every net core sdk version will integrate some of the functionality of the corresponding version of `nuget.exe cli` and then renamed it as its special nuget version.

**For an example**, `Net Core 3.1` sdk integrate part of [nuget exe 5.5.0](https://www.nuget.org/downloads) functions and then make its own dotnet nuget version called `5.5.0.4`(you see it by call `dotnet nuget --version` in CMD) while the related `nuget.exe cli` version is `5.5.0.6382`.

**Ultimately**, the functions between them are the same, but different version numbers are set to distinguish them.

Nuget.exe cli version:

[image]

dotnet nuget version

[image]

**And** `Net Core 3.0` sdk integrates part of `nuget.exe 5.3.1.6368` and create its own dotnet nuget version  `5.3.0.1` as a result.

**Actually**, you can see the nuget targets file and the corresponding function DLLs in this section under this path: `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\3.1.200` and you can see these parts of nuget functions.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer, I didn't realize you could just use```dotnet nuget --version ``` to look!